# jQuery ignorando as barras /

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho o seguinte código de `button`:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('View all items in your shopping cart')) ?>" class="button btn-inline-ver-carrinho" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>')"><span><span>Ver Carrinho</span></span></button>
```

No evento `onclick` deste `button`, ele me retorna uma `url` completa, porém quando eu utilizo esse código por meio do jQuery usando um `.append()` da seguinte maneira:

```
$j('#mini-cart').append("<button type='button' title='<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('View all items in your shopping cart')) ?>' class='button btn-inline-ver-carrinho' onclick='setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl("checkout/cart") ?>')'><span><span>Ver Carrinho</span></span></button>");
```

O mesmo código me retorna no `onclick` a `url`, porém sem as barras(/) e executando esse código normalmente sem ser por meio do jQuery, a `url` é mostrada corretamente.

Por meio do `php`, ele me retorna o seguinte: `onclick="setLocation("localhost/checkout/cart")"`

Por meio do `jQuery`, ele me retorna o seguinte:

```
onclick="setLocation("localhost  checkout  cart')'
```

Comment: atribui `<?php echo $this->getUrl("checkout/cart") ?>` a uma variavel, tenta ver se o valor vem correto. mostre o valor na sua pergunta, eu também não conheço a função setLocation ela é nativa? se não for poste o código dela também para podermos simular.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero Fazendo isso e dando um `console.log()` nessa variável, o valor vem corretamente.

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e forneça o valor que vem e a função setLocation(), assim poderemos testar e tentar descobrir o problema.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero Editei a pergunta, segundo com o que você disse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explicação

Aparentemente o teu problema é separação em variáveis para evitar prolemas com strings de múltiplas aspas simples e duplas.

Por isso recomendo utilizar criação de elemento dinâmica do jQuery e setar os atributos dele na mão, assim como está abaixo:

## Código

```js
function setLocation(href){
  document.location.href = href;
}

var btn = $('<button>'),
    spn = $('<span>'),
    str = 'View all items in your shopping cart',
    cls = 'button btn-inline-ver-carrinho',
    evt = "setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl(\"checkout/cart\") ?>')";
    
$(btn).attr({
  title: str,
  class: cls,
  onclick: evt
});

$(spn).html('<span>Ver Carrinho</span>');
$(btn).append(spn);


$('#mini-cart').append(btn);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=mini-cart >
</div>
```

## Observações

Não possuo o seu php por isso substitua onde eu coloquei fixo pelo código php que você possui que gera o que você precisa.

Comment: Era isso mesmo o problema, a questão das múltiplas aspas simples e duplas. Separando isso em variáveis igual você me explicou, deu certo. Muito obrigado por toda a ajuda e atenção.